# I used to develop with Zend 1, should I move to Zend 2 or to Symfony 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony

I am pretty familiar with Zend 1, I used it along with Doctrine 1.

Now I will be making all-new web application and I have to make a choice many of you probably had: which framework to use.

I started thinking about Symfony 2, as it feels kind of more integrated than Zend, has Doctrine already there.

But on the other hand I learned to make my controllers as tight as possible, making some operations (like getting some user data) in view templates. Symfony has this Twig engine, that's purely presentational.

I'm afraid that my habit to push some logic into View part of MVC won't be possible in purely presentational Symfony templates. Will disabling Twig make possible having some logic in templates?

My questions are:

- Can I put some logic in View in Symfony 2, by disabling Twig? Won't it violate Symfony's thought of what these templates should be?
- Being familiar with Zend concepts for several years, is it worth switching to Symfony for the sake of

  - out-of-the-box Doctrine integration
  - my IDE better integration (i use PHPStorm)?

Comment: Symfony [is not tied](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) to `twig` for templates. Also, I think your question may initiate debates like *"which framework is better and why"*. Please, clarify your question into specific points.

Comment: Symfony is highly modular and if you do not want to use any particular bundle like TWIG, you do not have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is just a pattern, if you do not like it, you can do not use it.

For the proof can read [this article](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2). Anyway twig is very flexible. You can declare your own [extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) which will provide some functions to fetch data from DB.

Previously, I also missed these functions, especially immediately after switching from ready-to-go CMS. But more often it is more convenient to get the data in the controller, logic move into services, or use the [embedded controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers).